# Make an s:DataGrid Item editor visible all the time

Tags: apache-flex

By defauld s:DataGrid displays an item editor after a cell is clicked. I would like to display the item editor all the time.

**How do I make the item editor visible all the time?** For example a column of check boxes.

Comment: I suppose you need to create an itemRenderer that looks like itemEditor then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Using editable controls in an item renderer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_3.html)

You can manage this situation in several ways, including the following:

1. In your item renderer, do not use controls that let users modify them (CheckBox, ComboBox, and others).
2. Create custom versions of these controls to prohibit user interaction with them.
   Use the rendererIsEditor property of the list control to specify that the item renderer is also an item editor. For more information, see Example: [Using an item renderer as an item editor.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/celleditor_8.html#202105)
3. Write your own code for the item renderer and hosting control to pass data back from the item renderer when you do let users interact with it.